# OPENING BULK URL USING ARRAY OF URLs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The following code is for a chrome extension that Iam trying to create. Number of windows that open are not 4. The number is different every time i run the code.

```
function open_all(){
    var testen = 'http://www.google.com',
        testar = 'http://www.yahoo.com',
        testcs = 'http://www.facebook.com',
        testcz = 'http://www.twitter.com',
        urls = [testen, testar, testcz, testcs],
        s;

    for(var i=0; i < 4; i++){
        s = urls[i];
        if(s) {
            if(s.substr(0,7)!='http://') s = 'http://'+s;
            window.open(s);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', open_all);
});
```

Comment: Your code runs very well on my end. So I wonder there's no problem with the attached codes here. Did you use "<button1 onclick="open_all()">" something inline JS like this in your html file since it's not allowed because of Content Security Policy.

Comment: You code works, perfectly, I don't see any problem. **Your problem is somewhere else** than in this snippet: add the full code of your extension or change the relevant part you're displaying. As of now, this question is just off-topic and useless.

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't waste anyone's time, including mine, if there wasn't a problem. I've clearly mentioned that the number of windows that open are not consistent. The code just most often opens only the firstt window.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `window.open` to open new tabs in an extension.

Use the appropriate [Chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs):

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: myUrl});
```

`"tabs"` permission not needed for this.